# MySQL Error "There can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT clause" even though I'm doing nothing wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE AlarmHistory
(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    startedStamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    finishedStamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
);
```

When trying to create the above table I get the following error: "SQL Error (1293): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause".

My question is this a bug? Because sure, I have two TIMESTAMP columns, but only ONE of them have a default definition. When I remove startedStamp I have no errors.

Comment: Your statement (after removing the last `,`) works as expected (MySQL 5.6.14). Are there any other columns?

Comment: Doesn't work in 5.5 though. What version are you (the OP) using? In 5.5, a `TIMESTAMP` with neither `DEFAULT` not `ON UPDATE` is treated as if it has *both* of them applied.

Comment: Server version: 5.5.35-0+wheezy1 (Debian)

Comment: That's the latest mySQL version according to packages.ubuntu.com. I think I'll just fix it with a before insert trigger. Or how do I get the newer version?

Comment: Nevermind, the answer below works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the MySQL manual, version 5.5, [Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

> With neither `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` nor `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it is the same as specifying both `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP
);
```

However,

> With a constant, the default is the given value. In this case, the column has no automatic properties at all.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0
);
```

So, this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE AlarmHistory
(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    startedStamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    finishedStamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/317de)

Answer (score 2):

This is the limitation in MYSQL 5.5 version. You need to update the version to 5.6.

**I was getting this error in adding a table in MYSQL**

> Incorrect table definition;  there can be only one TIMESTAMP column
>   with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause My new MYSQL

**table looks something like this.**

> create table table_name (col1 int(5) auto_increment primary key,  col2
>   varchar(300),  col3 varchar(500),  col4 int(3),  col5 tinyint(2), 
>   col6 timestamp default current_timestamp,  col7 timestamp default
>   current_timestamp on update current_timestamp,  col8 tinyint(1)
>   default 0,  col9 tinyint(1) default 1);

After some time of reading about changes in different MYSQL versions and some of the googling. I found out that there was some changes that were made in MYSQL version 5.6 over version 5.5.

This article will help you to resolve the issue.
http://www.oyewiki.com/MYSQL/Incorrect-table-definition-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column