# Simple PHP & SQL Query - Update value

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a query where I delete a record on call, however after other consideration I would rather just update the record on a is_deleted basis so that I can always have a record of whats been in the system, and or undelete that record at a later time.

My current query:

```
$delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM pin_status_types WHERE pinstatus_id='$delete'");
```

Instead of deleteing the record, i would rather change a value in a column from 0 to 1.

0 = false (not deleted)
1 = true (is deleted)

Correct me if I wrong, but wouldnt I do (Note; I added table. and column. to for note purposes.) something like below to achieve what I am after?

```
$delete=mysql_query("UPDATE table.pin_status_types SET column.is_deleted = 1 WHERE pinstatus_id='$delete'");
```

Comment: Wow! Total shot in the dark. Thanks :)

Comment: I always add deleted_date and deleted_by for a full audit trail. The final thing is to add a check that the row has not already been deleted. In fact you can just use the deleted_date to indicate the deleted status and do without the boolean column. NULL = not deleted, date = deleted. Remember you are going to have to add a check to every SELECT and UPDATE query as well.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am getting this now UPDATE command denied to user 'main_webapp'@'localhost' for table 'pin_status_types'

Comment: @LeviZoesch use PDO or MySQLi, the mysql_* driver is deprecated. Good luck!!

Comment: @DavidSoussan Ah thank you for the advice. I like the idea of audit trails... building an web application and will have multi-admin so having that is a great idea :) thank you!

Comment: Hard to say with so little code and not knowing which API you're using to connect with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query to:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pin_status_types SET is_deleted = 1, date_deleted = NOW() WHERE pinstatus_id = '{$delete}'"
```

Also, as David suggested in comments, you might want to add timestamp for when a record was deleted for audit purposed.

**Update**: changed query to cover the issue raised in your comment. Make the `date_deleted` column default to 0 instead on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23054647/747609) for more details on that.

[Please learn about and use PDO going forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I was able to see where I messed up and resolved it.

Comment: Oops, However I am adding deleted_on with timestamp of now. I get  Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause  because I already have a timestamp now for "created" column. Suggested work around?

Comment: You are using an old version on MySQL, I'll update my answer to cover that.

Comment: phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.7 documentation »

Comment: Very nice. Success! Thank you for the great ideas. I will write everything to PDO prior to launch. TY